# Restructure repetitive component to get rendered within a map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While I wrote my component as much DRY as I could, I wonder if there is a better way to render `ConnectButton` through a map function that takes [linkedIn, twitter, researchGate] as an array. I tried different things, but that's as good as I could get it. (I simplified the code a bit to the relevant. The original version is by a lot longer.)

```
const Component = () => {
  const ConnectButton = ({ icon, title }) => (
    <MenuItem>
      <ListItemIcon className={classes.listItemIcon}>
        <Icon className={classes.connectIcon} icon={icon} />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary={title} />
    </MenuItem>
  );

  const renderConnectMenu = () => {
    if (!profileInfo) {
      return;
    }

    const linkedIn = profileInfo.linkedIn;
    const twitter = profileInfo.twitter;
    const researchGate = profileInfo.researchGate;

    return (
      <div>
        {linkedIn && <ConnectButton icon={faLinkedin} title="LinkedIn" />}
        {twitter && <ConnectButton icon={faTwitter} title="Twitter" />}
        {researchGate && (
          <ConnectButton icon={faResearchgate} title="Research Gate" />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  };

  render(
    <>
      [...]
      {renderConnectMenu()}
      [...]
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 properties that define the rendering of a button: a field from `profileInfo`, icon and title. So we will need an array of objects with these properties in order to render them with `.map`.

I am not sure what kind of date the `profileInfo` fields hold so I named the property as `shouldRender` based on its usage.

```
const renderConnectMenu = () => {
  if (!profileInfo) {
    return;
  }

  const buttons = [
    {
      shouldRender: profileInfo.linkedIn,
      icon: faLinkedin,
      title: 'LinkedIn',
    },
    {
      shouldRender: profileInfo.twitter,
      icon: faLinkedin,
      title: 'Twitter',
    },
    {
      shouldRender: profileInfo.researchGate,
      icon: faLinkedin,
      title: 'Research Gate',
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      {buttons.map(
        (button) =>
          button.shouldRender && (
            <ConnectButton
              key={button.title}
              icon={button.icon}
              title={button.title}
            />
          ),
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

It might look a bit weird when you have a few items to render. So I wouldn't recommend this approach if there are just 2-3 items unless there is a possibility of extending the list. It's okay to keep it as it is now.